# Are previous branch builds saved anywhere? I'm looking for the 3.0 viewport compositing branch that never made it to main

Tags: versions

I know about the collection of basically all the previous release builds, but I'm looking for a branch that had an experimental feature that never made it to a release. I'd really like to experiment with it.

Comment: Have you looked there yet? https://builder.blender.org/download/patch/archive/ you need to know the patch id though

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Previous branch builds are maintained in the [experimental build archive](https://builder.blender.org/download/experimental/archive/).

But No.  Not every branch is kept and not every build from a branch, and only official branches.  So you may or may not be able to find what you're looking for.

On the other hand, the git repository has the necessary tags to allow building any branch at any point. You could try that path if you need the feat.

NOTE: The same thing is true for the patch build archive mentioned in a comment on your question; as well as the daily and other builds maintained there.