# can't find light linking branch for 3.6

Tags: lighting

Is there a way to find the light linking experimental component for 3.6 (mac)?
I can't upgrade to 4.0 because of hardware.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are previous branch builds saved anywhere? I'm looking for the 3.0 viewport compositing branch that never made it to main](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260062/are-previous-branch-builds-saved-anywhere-im-looking-for-the-3-0-viewport-comp) The problem might be, as stated in the answer, not every branch is kept so you might have no luck. But if you want to search somewhere, I would start at the given link there.

Comment: thank you! I have seen this and looked through this section in the bender website before posting.

Comment: Oh, okay... so when you already know the official repository I'm not sure what you were asking for... "a way to find" any other site that's not official would be to ask Google and hope there are inofficial/private archives for unfinished branches, because Blender will surely not provide multiple archives for abandoned branches.

Comment: Hello. yaelblender. Thanks for your research before posting. I think Gordon is right, though,@Marty Fouts has answered this question as comprehensively as any of us can, and it's fair to close this post as a duplicate. This must be frustrating.. I wish we could do more.